# Mosestokenizer issue: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, nlp, anaconda, nltk, tokenize

Can't figure out why is this problem appearing.

```
from mosestokenizer import MosesDetokenizer

with MosesDetokenizer('en') as detokenize:
    print(detokenize(["hi", 'my', 'name', 'is', 'artem']))
```

This is what I get:

```
stdbuf was not found; communication with perl may hang due to stdio buffering.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ArtemLaptiev\Documents\GitHub\temp\foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    with MosesDetokenizer('en') as detokenize:
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mosestokenizer\detokenizer.py", line 47, in __init__
    super().__init__(argv)
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\toolwrapper.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.start()
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\toolwrapper.py", line 92, in start
    cwd=self.cwd
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\ProgramFiles\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Please use  https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sacremoses` instead of `moses`.

```
pip install -U sacremoses
```

and

```
from sacremoses import MosesTokenizer, MosesDetokenizer
with MosesDetokenizer() as detokenize:
    print(detokenize(["hi", 'my', 'name', 'is', 'artem']))
```

for complete details [sacremoses](https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses)